# Unable to see the Popularity Trends and Views for site landing page

Tags: sharepoint-online, landing-page, page-view, popularity-trends

I am aware of the the feature - `Popularity Trends` which helps us to find out the number of views of all the pages. At the moment, I am able to see the number of views for all the pages except the `Landing Page`.

Why am I unable to see the popularity trends for the `Landing Page`?

Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean about the "landing page"? Do you mean SharePoint default pages? /default.aspx?

If you mean SP default page, this is by design. "Popularity Trends" button works for “a page or an item in a library”. Default.aspx (Page) is not present in a Library. Default.aspx is in All Files Folder(You can check it in SharePoint Designer > All Files).

[image]

You can set another page(in page library/site page library) as homepage, then you can use this button.

Comment: Landing page is the homepage of the site on which I am working. I have created it by a script and named it as Default.aspx. The issue here is that I am unable to get the number of views for this page. I am able to see the number of views for the other pages though.

Comment: This is by design. See my answer in above reply. You can set another page(in page library/site page library) as homepage, then you can use this button.

Comment: How often can we see this report being updated?  lets say if I hit a particular page 5 times back to back then would I be able to see it in the report instantly?

Comment: What do you mean about "hit a page 5 times"?

Comment: Hit a page 5 times meaning visiting it 5 times.

Comment: I have a question, why am I unable to see the popularity trend for pages in sites that are 2 level down the hierarchy? (i.e A->B->C and I want to get the result for the site C)